# Continuum fluid theory

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

It is written in this article: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~yktsang/4520/basic_fluid.pdf
"In the continuum model of fluids, physical quantities are considered to be varying continuously in space, for example, we may speak of a velocity field ~u(~x, t) or a temperature field T(~x, t). The “local” values of such quantities at a single point P in space should be understood as average values over a small region of size Lp about P."

Then in the example he took a small volume Dx and Dy:
" We now consider the various forces acting on a fluid element of sides ∆x, ∆y and ∆z in our channel flow problem"

My question is, this fluid element is it equal to Lp? If no, does the pressure in his study is an average value over a small region of size Lp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$, and $\Delta z$ all have size $L_p$. And yes, his pressure is an average over a  small region of size $L_p$.

Comment: but how for example P(x) is an average value over a small region of Lp and we are studying over a small region?

Comment: For one thing, in this case he wants to find the force on the side of the cube, which is related to the average pressure, so an average of $p$ over a length scale $L_p$ makes sense here. Also, he says there should be a big separation in scale between $L_p$ and the molecular scale, so the local average of the pressure shouldn't change much if you average $p$ over a much smaller window like $L_p/100$, so you can imagine you are doing that to compute the pressure on the box.

Comment: We do the same study for hydrostatic pressure and we get p(z+dz) = p(z) + mgdz and after this equation is applied between 2 points of fluid. These 2 points also represents the average of 2 small volume of fluids but we made the study only on one small volume.

Comment: Can we say that dz is small such we can consider the point at position z in the fluid is the average between p(z+dz) and p(z) is p(z)?

Comment: You are supposed to think of $p(z)$ being the average of a box centered on $z$ and $p(z+dz)$ being the average of a box centered on $z+dz$. It is important that these will be different so you can get a net force on your box.

Comment: Ah ok great. Can we say that the point at (z+dz/2) has the average value of the small volume that we are studying it? Do the shear forces on the other hand are also the average values?

Comment: Yes the point $z+dz/2$ would have the average value of the box. Shear forces come from differences in the velocties on either side of the box, just like the force from pressure came from differences in pressure on either side of the box.

Comment: Just sorry for opening the thread again, when we study shear force on one side, the value is also an average value?

Comment: yes, the shear force is also an average.